# How to simplify a summation using mathematica

Tags: summation

I have the following summation I would like to simplify:
$f(y)=\frac{1}{\left(2^{N}-1-N\right) \sqrt{2 \pi}} \sum_{k=2}^{N} \frac{\left(\begin{array}{l}
N \\
k
\end{array}\right)}{\sqrt{k \sigma^{2}+1}} e^{-0.5 y^{2} /\left(k \sigma^{2}+1\right)}$
$N>>1$ is a positive integer.

*The Mathematica code I tried is below:*

```
f=Sum[Binomial[N,k]Exp[(-0.5y^2)/(k *(sigma^2)+1)]/(Sqrt[k *(sigma^2)+1]), {k, 2, N}]
g=FullSimplify[f]
```

The output just displays what I have already written. It is not doing any simplification. Can someone tell me if this can be simplified using Mathematica? If yes, what should be the appropriate command?

**NB:** I am totally new to mathematica and hence asking.

Comment: Post code, not pictures, please.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: Is there a relationship between $x$ and $y$, or are they independent variables?

Comment: @Roman, $x$ is not related to $y$.

Comment: So why exactly did you write $k=x/\sigma^2$? Where does $x$ come into play?

Comment: @Roman, Actually that's just an extra info. Not needed for computation. I will edit the question.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please add in Mathematica format the code you have tried,  Showing that you have made some effort will encourage readers to help.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I have made the edits by adding the Mathematica code I tried.

Comment: Please at least look up how to spell [`Exp`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exp.html) and [`Sqrt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sqrt.html), and make your code actually match the formula (using parentheses). Also, [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) is a reserved symbol in Mathematica, don't use it as a variable.

Comment: @Roman, Thanks for pointing out. I will edit.

Comment: I suspect that there is no simplification and you might be better off looking for an approximation.  Note that for a fixed $y$ and $\sigma$ a plot of $\log f(y, N, \sigma)$ vs $N$ (with $N$ appropriately represented by `n` in *Mathematica*) looks very linear with a slope dependent only on $\sigma$.

Comment: @JimB, Thank you! One follow-up question:  I am interested in an approximation  to the summation which is in the form of a  Gaussian function $e^{(y-a)^{2}/b}$ form. Is there a way to do that in Mathematica?

Comment: That would mean that the log of the summation would have a form of $(y-a)^2/b$, so either `LinearModelFit` or `NonlinearModelFit` should be helpful.  But you might want to write that up as a separate question (along with any attempts you've made with *Mathematica*).

Comment: In general, one thing you can do is add assumptions to `FullSimplify`, which amount to e.g. telling Mathematica that `n` is a positive integer, e.g. `g = FullSimplify[f, n \[Element] Integers && n >2 && y \[Element] Reals && sigma \[Element] Reals && 1 + k sigma^2 > 0]`. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to help here, but just so you know the strategy!

Comment: Also note that machine numbers like `0.5` will be treated differently than "exact" numbers like `1/2`. When not doing numerics, it's important to avoid decimals!